# Python- How can I view os.walk file contents without printing the file paths each time?

Tags: python, loops, raw-input

I use this script to recursively go through a directory and view file contents. However, when I type in the file's contents, it shows at the top and reprints the entire list of files again. I just want the list of file paths to print once and then the user can open as many files as they want without the list printing each time. Hope that makes sense.

```
import os
while True:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home"):
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, file))     
    fname = raw_input('Enter filepath to view '
                    '(leave empty to proceed without viewing another file):')

    if not fname:
        break

    f = open(fname, 'r')
    print f.read()
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? I suspect that doing that will reveal the problem to you.

Comment: That was an error in posting. It's correct in my original script. I'll go ahead and fix it. I need it to work without the first print statement where it prints the paths but I don't know how to get it to work. I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move printing the directory tree outside of while loop:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home"):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file))     

while True:
    fpath = raw_input('Enter filepath to view '
                    '(leave empty to proceed without viewing another file):')

    if not fpath:
        break

    with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
        print f.read()
```

Comment: "with open open(fpath, 'r') as f:" invalid syntax